# Where the materialized views stored in metadata of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, metadata, postgresql-9.3

My database is postgresql 9.3.5

we created some materialized views. we are able seeing those are in views folder through pgadmin tool
but our issue is we are not able to finding out those materialized views in metadata
we checked in information_schema and all catalogs.
we found all tables,views and schemas except materialized views in metadata

Thanks
Ragav

Comment: `pg_class` with `relkind = 'm'`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name.We found all materialized view names.But there is no column names and datatypes of materialized views

Comment: You need to join that to `pg_attributes`. Btw: there is also `pg_matviews` for the list of materialized views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query like this will give you an overview of the materialized views and their columns:

```
select ns.nspname as schemaname, 
       mv.relname as matviewname,
       string_agg(atr.attname ||' '||pg_catalog.format_type(atr.atttypid, NULL), ', ') as columns
from pg_class mv
  join pg_namespace ns on mv.relnamespace = ns.oid
  join pg_attribute atr 
    on atr.attrelid = mv.oid 
   and atr.attnum > 0 
   and not atr.attisdropped
where mv.relkind = 'm'
group by ns.nspname, mv.relname;
```